# MySQL Server Installation Failed 8.0.13

Tags: mysql, failed-installation

[Fail Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FttS0.png)
While Trying to install MySQL server 8.0.13 i'm getting an error.
I'm running running mysql-installer-community-8.0.13.0.msi.
I have Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Re. x(64) and x(86) installed in computer.
My Operating system is 64 bit. 
Where, Mysql Installer is Windows (x86, 32-bit), MSI Installer

Comment: Hi there. Well, you haven't got a lot of details here (OS, admin rights etc.). You're running `mysql-installer-community-8.0.13.0.msi` installation or web community edition (which is only 16Mb)? First one weighs more, but have all necessary stuff

Comment: i'm running mysql-installer-community-8.0.13

Comment: i have the same issue, running  on windows 10, build 17134.407.

I don't have any running process regarding `oracle-mysql`and I tried different  server versions (5.7 and 8.0.13) but without any success.
I have even disabled (UAC) completely but it didn't.. even when I used a third party application (xampp) I couldn't run the mysql server.
I am thankfull for any hint

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same error and fix it by following steps.

> 1. Execute MySQL Installer.
> 2. Select "MySQL Server" for installation in the "Select Products and Features" page.
> 3. Unselect "Server data files" feature by expanding the "MySQL Server" node in the "Products/Features To Be Installed" tree view.
> 4. Proceed with the installation in a normal fashion.

original source: https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?169,685186,685186#msg-685186